# Storing a list of entities in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I am wondering what is the best way to store a list of entities in Umbraco.

Say, I have a page that list a bunch of contact information (name, company address, phone number, etc...). I want a web administrator to be able to easily create and edit them inside Umbraco.

Should I be creating a new **Data Type** call Contact. And have those properties in that Data Type?

If so, is this a good practice? I always think each node in Umbraco is suppose to be a page.

If not, what other options do I have?

Thank you,

Chi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each node in Umbraco does **not** necessarily have to be a page. You can have child nodes (*not* pages) which constitute a list to be displayed on their parent node (a page).

For example: you could have a **document type** called *ContactList*. The corresponding **template** will look for all child nodes having the **document type** *Contact* and list them. The *Contact* document type has all the properties you need for a contact. You do not need to assign a template to the *Contact* document type (or a *NullTemplate*, displaying nothing).

**Advantages** of using nodes for each contact:

- The user can use the publishing features of content nodes
- The user can manipulate the sort order within Umbraco as with any node
- The data of each *Contact* is stored in the *umbraco.config* and can be interrogated like any property of any node (xslt, razor).

Of course, there are **limits**. For example, if you have more than 40-50 contacts, this will be difficult to use. Or if you have to regularly import or synchronize contacts, some additional programming effort will be required.

Answer (score 1):

Today the best way to store list of entities which will not have pages is Archetype. It's an Umbraco 7 property editor that wraps other installed property editors. By wrapping the other properties, Archetype allows for custom and repeatable fieldset mashups. Archetype documentation - https://github.com/kgiszewski/ArchetypeManual